# Data type varchar of receiving variable is not equal to the data type nvarchar of column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am receiving an error message for this one. The error message is:

> Data type varchar of receiving variable is not equal to the data type
>   nvarchar of column 'VEHICLE_ID2_FW'

Please help, thanks

```
DECLARE @IMPORTID INT
DECLARE @LASTID INT
DECLARE @VEHICLEID VARCHAR (20)

SELECT @LASTID = (SELECT LAST_REFERENCE_FW FROM REFERENCE_FW WHERE RECORD_TYPE_FW = 'VEHICLES_ORDERS_FW' AND REFERENCE_FIELD_FW = 'VEHICLE_ID2_FW' AND ARCHIVE_STATUS_FW ='N')
SELECT @IMPORTID = (SELECT IMPORT_ID_FW FROM VEHICLES_ORDERS_FW WHERE RECORD_NUMBER_FW = %RECORD_NUMBER_FW%)
SELECT @VEHICLEID = (SELECT VEHICLE_ID2_FW FROM VEHICLES_ORDERS_FW WHERE RECORD_NUMBER_FW = %RECORD_NUMBER_FW%)

IF @IMPORTID IS NOT NULL AND @VEHICLEID IS NULL

BEGIN
UPDATE VEHICLES_ORDERS_FW
SET @LASTID = VEHICLES_ORDERS_FW.VEHICLE_ID2_FW = @LASTID+1
FROM VEHICLES_ORDERS_FW
WHERE RECORD_NUMBER_FW = %RECORD_NUMBER_FW%;

UPDATE VEHICLES_ORDERS_FW
SET VEHICLES_ORDERS_FW.VEHICLE_ID2_FW = 'FW'+VEHICLE_ID2_FW
FROM VEHICLES_ORDERS_FW
WHERE RECORD_NUMBER_FW = %RECORD_NUMBER_FW%

END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your script with this script below

```
DECLARE @IMPORTID INT
DECLARE @LASTID INT
DECLARE @VEHICLEID VARCHAR (20)

SELECT @LASTID = (SELECT LAST_REFERENCE_FW FROM REFERENCE_FW WHERE RECORD_TYPE_FW like N'VEHICLES_ORDERS_FW' AND REFERENCE_FIELD_FW LIKE N'VEHICLE_ID2_FW' AND ARCHIVE_STATUS_FW  LIKE N'N')

SELECT @IMPORTID = (SELECT IMPORT_ID_FW FROM VEHICLES_ORDERS_FW WHERE CAST(RECORD_NUMBER_FW  AS NVARCHAR) LIKE CONCAT(N'%', CAST(RECORD_NUMBER_FW AS NVARCHAR),N'%'))

SELECT @VEHICLEID = (SELECT VEHICLE_ID2_FW FROM VEHICLES_ORDERS_FW WHERE CAST(RECORD_NUMBER_FW  AS NVARCHAR)  = CONCAT(N'%', CAST(RECORD_NUMBER_FW AS NVARCHAR),N'%'))

IF @IMPORTID IS NOT NULL AND @VEHICLEID IS NULL

BEGIN
UPDATE VEHICLES_ORDERS_FW
SET @LASTID = @LASTID+1
FROM VEHICLES_ORDERS_FW
WHERE CAST(RECORD_NUMBER_FW  AS NVARCHAR) LIKE CONCAT(N'%', CAST(RECORD_NUMBER_FW AS NVARCHAR),N'%');

UPDATE VEHICLES_ORDERS_FW
SET VEHICLES_ORDERS_FW.VEHICLE_ID2_FW = CONCAT(N'FW',VEHICLE_ID2_FW)
FROM VEHICLES_ORDERS_FW
WHERE CAST(RECORD_NUMBER_FW  AS NVARCHAR) LIKE CONCAT(N'%', CAST(RECORD_NUMBER_FW AS NVARCHAR),N'%');
```

Comment: Thanks it actually works, I just removed the concat record number because it is fixed number in the system that happens only on that particular record.

Comment: @user3585538 +1 to you for modifying solution as per your need!

Answer (score 0):

Mabey here is the problem:

```
set @LASTID = VEHICLES_ORDERS_FW.VEHICLE_ID2_FW = @LASTID + 1
```

will be good if you provide table structure.

Comment: still having an error message "ata type int of receiving variable is not equal to the data type nvarchar of column 'VEHICLE_ID2_FW'."

Comment: VEHICLE_ID2_FW = VARCHAR(20)
LAST_REFERENCE_FW = Integer

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change table datatype. you can type cast column using `CAST` or `CONVERT`

Comment: If you need to do CAST/CONVERT, take a few seconds and consider your db design. (Often indicates bad design.)